# What type of attacks can be carried on for an web application

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

My company has designed an web application and its going to be hosted soon, I would like to know what type of attacks can be carried on the web application to test the security of my web application

Right now I have tried the following attacks

- Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)
- Client-State Manipulation
- Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF)
- Cross Site Script Inclusion (XSSI)
- Path Traversal
- Denial of service attacks
- DoS via ajax
- Phishing via ajax
- SQL injection

I have carried out the above mentioned attacks and I wish to know any other type of attacks to test my web application before its going to be hosted.

Comment: This question is overly broad and could only be properly answered with several books.

Comment: As the previous comment, and the answer below, both mentioned - this topic is simply HUGE, and is not a simple question. As mentioned, do some research, such as [OWASP](http://owasp.org), also check out SANS 25, Mitre's CWE, and any number of books and sites on the matter. And that will still not be complete... Perhaps you can ask a more specific question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a huge number of possible attacks. The ones you mention cover most of it, but things like session management problems, DOM injection, misconfigured AJAX cross-domain policy, etc. are all problems too.

Check out the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main) project, and the [OWASP Cheat Sheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets) for a more comprehensive list.